# how can i search a JSON API using search bar in ionic

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I want to perform a search on json and display it on screen

Check out this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/lPVWC0?p=preview) i made.Can someone tell me how can i perform a search and display on screen and use that data .

```
<div class="list list-inset">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/k1JhuvOMqy06DZYY4SlV?p=preview) but in case you don't get it you need to add ng-model in your search bar so change this line to

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model='query'>
```

And then in your ng-repeat do:

```
<article ng-repeat="object in yifito | filter : query">
```

And it works, I just checked (and forked)

Comment: This is not working when i search some other movie it displays nothing

Comment: Well, does batman even exist here? Cause I cant see. I dont understand what you're saying, why would you expect it to work for other movies, i.e. movies that don't exist in a list?

Comment: Batman doesn't exist in your JSON - https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=50

Comment: You can use a normal JSON without a limit=50, and then use a limitTo filter on front end same as you did with query.

Answer (score 0):

Add ng-model to the input field and filter the ng-repeat using the function

```
 <ion-content>
    <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
      </label>
    </div>

    <section class="list">
      <article ng-repeat="object in yifito|filter:myfilter ">
        <a href="{{object.url}}" target="_system" onclick="window.open('{{object.url}}',_system,'location=yes')" class="item">
          <img ng-src="{{object.medium_cover_image}}">
          <h2 class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.title}}</h2>
          <p class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.genres}}</p>
          <p class="noWhiteSpace">Year {{object.year}} Rating {{object.rating}}</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </article>
    </section>
  </ion-content>
```

Myfilter function logic in js file

```
$scope.myfilter = function(obj) {
    var val = true;
    if($scope.search && !obj.title || 
       $scope.search && !obj.Rating  || 
       $scope.search && !obj.year
    ) {
      val = false;
    } 
        return val;
  }
```